# Store bool value of condition

Tags: pine-script

I want to code a Stop Loss that becomes activate after `close`reaches a certain price level. The condition is:

```
SL_Long_threshold = strategy.position_avg_price * (1+ActivationPercent)
SL_Long_active = close >= SL_Long_threshold
```

Once the Stop Loss is activated it is supposed to stay active until the position is sold. The problem is that `SL_Long_active` is no longer true when new bars close at a value lower than `SL_Long_threshold`.

How do I keep the value of `SL_Long_active` true even if new bars make it false?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `var` keyword.

```
var is the keyword used for assigning and one-time initializing of the variable.
```

Something like this:

```
var SL_Long_active = false
SL_Long_active := (close >= SL_Long_threshold) ? true : SL_Long_active // If threshold is reached, make it true. Keep its value otherwise
```

Then you need to reset this according to your strategy.

Comment: Hey Vitruvius, thanks for the quick reply. For some reason, SL_Long_active is true even when the condition is not met. Maybe this has to do with your last sentence about having to reset the variable according to my strategy. Could you clarify this?

Comment: When you have a `var` variable, it will keep its value unless you assign a new value to it. So, at some point you need to do `SL_Long_active := false`. Probably when you exit a trade so it would be ready for the next trade.

Answer (score 0):

You need some time with closed eyes to better understand how Pine script works.

On every bar (whatever the time frame), your code will start with a clean state. When your code have run on that bar, there will be a few calculated values you made, like:

```
my_var = close * open + 1234
```

You should be thinking of `my_var` as a huge Array which is built by Pine, bar-by-bar. At the end of every "turn", Pine will append the current value of `my_var` to the end of that huge array, then RESET everything and start on the next bar.
If you are running your script on a token/ticker symbol that has 17500 candles, then your Pine script will run 17499 times, starting from the very first candle, to reach to the current candle and every variable you have created will have 17499 past values in it (one for each candle).

This is why you can have `my_var[3]` which is the third previous value of `my_var`. Thinking of arrays, `my_var[0]` is the same as `my_var`, which is the current value of `my_var` in the current run.

So at the end of every candle, everything will reset and start over again. Your statement:

```
SL_Long_active = close >= SL_Long_threshold
```

will be true for some candles, but will be false for others. If you calculate it this way, it will recalculate on every bar, effectively destroying its previous state, which is not what you want.

The only way to prevent this *reset*, Pine has a klunky solution, you need to prefix a variable with `var`. This will define the variable, you can even set a value to it, but it will never reset, however its value will still be appended to that huge array, so if you use such a variable in the previous example, it will also have 17499 past values at the current candle.

Changing such a variable's value on every candle has no use, you could just have used a normal variable instead. The `var` variables' power shows if you only change their values when a certain condition happens.

```
var my_var = false
if close > close[1]
    my_var := true
else
    my_var := false
```

Or better (because of more deeper, hidden klunkyness of Pine) you should use a ternary operator:

```
var my_var = false
my_var := close > close[1] ? true : false // You don't need to define true/false, this is just an example placeholder
```

The line with `var my_var = false` will only run once, on the very first run so it will not redefine `my_var` in every turn.

What to watch for:

- if you set a variable's value in your script once or first, you have to use `=`, like `my_var = 5`
- however if you are redefining a variable's value later in the script, you must use `:=` instead
- with `IF/ELSE` you have to indent the second/third/... lines below the `if <whatever>` with exactly 4 spaces or 1 tab. Otherwise Pine will think it is a new line and not part of the `IF` block.

I wish Tradingview have built a debugger, that would make Pine very much understandable by stepping over the code on one bar, then seeing the "code" hop to the next bar, and running again from the 1st line.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks so much for taking the time and providing me with these insights, this was really helpful. My script now does what it was supposed to do...!